# Q: Debugging Jenkins node/agent creation & configuration

Tags: jenkins, agents

I've got an issue with Jenkins 2.6-1.1 running on CentOS v7.2.1511. I am using the Crowd 2 integration plugin v.1.8 and the [Matrix Authorization Strategy plugin v.1.3.2](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Authorization+Strategy+Plugin) for authentication and authorization, respectively. Security is configured for "Project-based Matrix authorization strategy".

In my Jenkins configuration, I employ two group assignments on the Crowd server: **jenkins-administrators** and **jenkins-users**. **jenkins-admininstrators** has every permission enabled. **jenkins-users** have permission to:

- Overall: Read, RunScripts
- Agent: Build, Configure, Connect, Create
- Job: Build, Cancel, Configure, Create, Delete, Discover, Read, Workspace
- Run: Delete, Update
- View: Configure, Create, Read
- SCM

**jenkins-administrators** obviously have all of these permissions enabled as well.

The issue is that, at some point, users who are in both **jenkins-administrators** and **jenkins-users** ceased having the ability to **configure nodes** or **create new nodes**. What I mean by this is that, when the user clicks on the link to configure a node, or clicks **OK** on the new node (`/computer/node`) page, the post goes through, but a page is never returned.

If I remove the user from the **jenkins-administrators** group, they are able to add and configure nodes as expected.

If I configure the user such that they are in the **jenkins-admininstrators** group solely, they are unable to login (which seems like it could be related).

I tried modifying the security matrix so that **jenkins-administrators** and **jenkins-users** had the same configuration in re: to nodes, but this didn't change anything.

Outside of the slave logs, and the occasional message to `/var/log/messages`, there doesn't appear to be anything relevant in `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`.

Any suggestions on how I can [configure Jenkins logging](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging) to show me information that is more relevant to node configuration and creation, or any suggestions in general on how I might observe the node creation and configuration process?